# How to overlay multiple landscape regions from a single input to a new portrait video? FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, electron

I have an electron program that selects multiple regions of a landscape video and lets you rearrange them in a portrait canvas. I'm having trouble building the proper ffmpeg command to create the video. I have this somewhat working. I can export 2 layers, but i can't export if i only have 1 layer or if i have 3 or more layers selected.

2 regions of video selected

```
layers [
  { top: 0, left: 658, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 262, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
newPositions [
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
filtergraph [0]crop=576:1080:658:0,scale=576:1080[v0];[0]crop=576:324:0:262,scale=576:324[v1];[v0][v1]overlay=0:0:0:0[out]

No Error export successful
```

1 region selected

```
layers [ { top: 0, left: 650, width: 576, height: 1080 } ]
newPositions [ { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 1080 } ]
filtergraph [0]crop=576:1080:650:0,scale=576:1080[v0];[v0]overlay=0:0[out]

FFmpeg error: [fc#0 @ 000001dd3b6db0c0] Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad overlay
Error initializing complex filters: Invalid argument
```

3 regions of video selected

```
layers [
  { top: 0, left: 641, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 250, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 },
  { top: 756, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
newPositions [
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 },
  { top: 756, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
filtergraph [0]crop=576:1080:641:0,scale=576:1080[v0];[0]crop=576:324:0:250,scale=576:324[v1];[0]crop=576:324:0:756,scale=576:324[v2];[v0][v1][v2]overlay=0:0:0:0:0:756[out]

FFmpeg error: [AVFilterGraph @ 0000018faf2189c0] More input link labels specified for filter 'overlay' than it has inputs: 3 > 2
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000018faf2189c0] Error linking filters

FFmpeg error: Failed to set value '[0]crop=576:1080:698:0,scale=576:1080[v0];[0]crop=576:324:0:264,scale=576:324[v1];[0]crop=576:324:0:756,scale=576:324[v2];[v0][v1][v2]overlay=0:0:0:0:0:0[out]' for option 'filter_complex': Invalid argument
Error parsing global options: Invalid argument
```

I can't figure out how to construct the proper overlay command. Here is the js code i'm using from my electron app.

```js
ipcMain.handle('export-video', async (_event, args) => {
  const { videoFile, outputName, layers, newPositions } = args;
  const ffmpegPath = path.join(__dirname, 'bin', 'ffmpeg');
  const outputDir = checkOutputDir();
  
  // use same video for each layer as input
  // crop, scale, and position each layer
  // overlay each layer on top of each other

  // export video
  console.log('layers', layers);
  console.log('newPositions', newPositions);

  let filtergraph = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    const { top, left, width, height } = layers[i];
    const { width: newWidth, height: newHeight } = newPositions[i];
    const filter = `[0]crop=${width}:${height}:${left}:${top},scale=${newWidth}:${newHeight}[v${i}];`;
    filtergraph += filter;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    const filter = `[v${i}]`;
    filtergraph += filter;
  }

  filtergraph += `overlay=`;
  for (let i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    const { top: newTop, left: newLeft } = newPositions[i];
    const overlay = `${newLeft}:${newTop}:`;
    filtergraph += overlay;
  }

  filtergraph = filtergraph.slice(0, -1); // remove last comma
  filtergraph += `[out]`;
  
  console.log('filtergraph', filtergraph);

  const ffmpeg = spawn(ffmpegPath, [
    '-i', videoFile,
    '-filter_complex', filtergraph,
    '-map', '[out]',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
    '-crf', '18',
    '-y',
    path.join(outputDir, `${outputName}`)
  ]);  

  ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`FFmpeg output: ${data}`);
  });

  ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`FFmpeg error: ${data}`);
  });

  ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`FFmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
    // event.reply('ffmpeg-export-done'); // Notify the renderer process
  });
});
```

Any advice might be helpful, The docs are confusing, Thanks.

**Edit**
I'm getting closer with this
Output:

```
layers [
  { top: 0, left: 677, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 240, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
newPositions [
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
filtergraph [0]crop=576:1080:677:0,scale=576:1080[v0];[0]crop=576:324:0:240,scale=576:324[v1];[0][v0]overlay=0:0[o0];[o0][v1]overlay=0:0[o1]
```

```js
ipcMain.handle('export-video', async (_event, args) => {
  const { videoFile, outputName, layers, newPositions } = args;
  const ffmpegPath = path.join(__dirname, 'bin', 'ffmpeg');
  const outputDir = checkOutputDir();
  
  // use same video for each layer as input
  // crop, scale, and position each layer
  // overlay each layer on top of each other

  // export video
  console.log('layers', layers);
  console.log('newPositions', newPositions);

  let filtergraph = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    const { top, left, width, height } = layers[i];
    const { width: newWidth, height: newHeight } = newPositions[i];
    const filter = `[0]crop=${width}:${height}:${left}:${top},scale=${newWidth}:${newHeight}[v${i}];`;
    filtergraph += filter;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      filtergraph += `[0][v${i}]overlay=`;
    } else {
      filtergraph += `[o${i-1}][v${i}]overlay=`;
    }
    const { top: newTop, left: newLeft } = newPositions[i];
    let overlay = '';
    if (i !== layers.length - 1) {
      overlay = `${newLeft}:${newTop}[o${i}];`;
    } else {
      overlay = `${newLeft}:${newTop};`;
    }
    filtergraph += overlay;
  }

  filtergraph = filtergraph.slice(0, -1); // remove last comma
  filtergraph += `[o${layers.length-1}]`;
  
  console.log('filtergraph', filtergraph);

  const ffmpeg = spawn(ffmpegPath, [
    '-i', videoFile,
    '-filter_complex', filtergraph,
    '-map', `[o${layers.length-1}]`,
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
    '-crf', '18',
    '-y',
    path.join(outputDir, `${outputName}`)
  ]);  

  ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`FFmpeg output: ${data}`);
  });

  ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`FFmpeg error: ${data}`);
  });

  ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`FFmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
    // event.reply('ffmpeg-export-done'); // Notify the renderer process
  });
});
```

The problem I'm having now is that its overlaying the regions over the original input and keeping the landscape dimensions instead of making a portrait video.

Answer (score 0):

To stack multiple videos of the same width vertically, use the vstack filter.

```
[0]crop=576:1080:641:0,scale=576:1080[v0];
[0]crop=576:324:0:250,scale=576:324[v1];
[0]crop=576:324:0:756,scale=576:324[v2];
[v0][v1][v2]vstack=inputs=3[out]
```

Comment: I'm not trying to stack vertically. i need it to be overlayed. I've tried using other stack commands but the videos flicker between captured regions. I can't use vstack. I'm just trying to figure out the proper overlay syntax. unless overlay can't be used to accomplish what i'm trying to do. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

1 region

```
layers [ { top: 0, left: 672, width: 576, height: 1080 } ]
newPositions [ { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 1080 } ]
filtergraph [0]crop=576:1080:672:0,scale=576:1080[l0]
```

2 regions

```
layers [
  { top: 0, left: 660, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 242, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
newPositions [
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
filtergraph [0]crop=576:1080:660:0,scale=576:1080[l0];[0]crop=576:324:0:242,scale=576:324[l1];[l0][l1]overlay=0:0[o0]
```

3 or more regions

```
layers [
  { top: 0, left: 665, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 238, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 },
  { top: 756, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
newPositions [
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 1080 },
  { top: 0, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 },
  { top: 756, left: 0, width: 576, height: 324 }
]
filtergraph [0]crop=576:1080:665:0,scale=576:1080[l0];[0]crop=576:324:0:238,scale=576:324[l1];[0]crop=576:324:0:756,scale=576:324[l2];[l0][l1]overlay=0:0[o0];[o0][l2]overlay=0:756[o1]
```

Export Handler

```js
ipcMain.handle('export-video', async (_event, args) => {
  const { videoFile, outputName, layers, newPositions } = args;
  const ffmpegPath = path.join(__dirname, 'bin', 'ffmpeg');
  const outputDir = checkOutputDir();
  
  console.log('layers', layers);
  console.log('newPositions', newPositions);

  let filtergraph = '';
  let overlayCount = -1;

  for (let i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    const { top, left, width, height } = layers[i];
    const { width: newWidth, height: newHeight } = newPositions[i];
    let filter = '';
    filter = `[0]crop=${width}:${height}:${left}:${top},scale=${newWidth}:${newHeight}[l${i}];`;
    filtergraph += filter;
  }

  let newLeft = 0;
  let newTop = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0 && layers.length > 1) {
      newLeft = newPositions[i+1].left;
      newTop = newPositions[i+1].top;
      filtergraph += `[l${i}][l${i+1}]overlay=${newLeft}:${newTop}[o${i}];`;
      overlayCount++;
    } else if (i < layers.length - 1) {
      newLeft = newPositions[i+1].left;
      newTop = newPositions[i+1].top;
      filtergraph += `[o${i-1}][l${i+1}]overlay=${newLeft}:${newTop}[o${i}];`;
      overlayCount++;
    }
  } 

  filtergraph = filtergraph.slice(0, -1); // remove last semicolon
  console.log('filtergraph', filtergraph);

  const ffmpeg = spawn(ffmpegPath, [
    '-i', videoFile,
    '-filter_complex', filtergraph,
    '-map', overlayCount > -1 ? `[o${overlayCount}]` : `[l0]`,
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
    '-crf', '18',
    '-y', path.join(outputDir, outputName)
  ]);  

  ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`FFmpeg output: ${data}`);
  });

  ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`FFmpeg error: ${data}`);
  });

  ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`FFmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
});
```